# How to determine traffic flow from server

Tags: networking, cisco

How can I  determine the path traffic takes from a server with 2 Ethernet ports, each port connecting to a separate switch.

The switches are not cable of layer3 so I cannot use HSPR where I could make the one switch the default gateway.

Is there a layer two solution I can Implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each server decides based on it's own routing table which interface to use when connecting out. Unless you use some special features like bonding, you should get useful output by entering `sudo ip route show`.

For example in my case the output looks like this:

```
root@mr-burns:~ ssh# ip route show
default via 10.60.0.1 dev em1 
10.20.0.0/16 via 10.60.0.165 dev em2
10.60.0.0/16 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.60.1.150 
10.60.0.0/16 dev em2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.60.1.151 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
```

I read this like following:

Let's say the destination is inside the network 10.20.0.0/16, it will use the interface em2 because of the second rule.

But if the destination is using the default gw because its not in any of the listed destination networks, it uses em1.